# AWS MSK. Kafka Connect - plugin class loading

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I am using Kafka Connect in MSK.
I have defined a plugin that points to a zip file in s3 - this works fine.
I have implemented [SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html) and uploaded the SMT jar into the **same** bucket and folder as the zip file of the plugin.
I define a new connector and this time I add the SMT using

```
transforms
```

I get an error message that the Class `com.x.y.z.MySMT` could not be found.
I verified that the jar is valid and contains the SMT.
Where should I put the SMT jar in order to make Kafka connect loading it?

Comment: Are you sure the JAR shouldn't be in the same ZIP, or a ZIP on its own (even though JAR files are ZIP-compatible formats)?

Comment: I am not sure .. I could not find any clear explanation in AWS docs. If I would use Kafka connect standalone - should I put the jar inside the zip or I could use them side by side?

Comment: Outside of MSK, zip files are never used at runtime. The plugin path needs to point at a folder above any _extracted_ zipped plugins, who's folders contain jars

Comment: @OneCricketeer Not sure I get your direction... You think that I need to extract the zip (get the jars under `/lib`), add my SMT jar and put everything in S3 folder in a flat structure?

Comment: I do not know how MSK loads plugins. I would like to believe it downloads the ZIPs then extracts them for you

Answer (score 1):

Pushing the SMT jar into the zip (under /lib) solved the class not found issue.

Comment: I am running into the same issue but I can't seem to find a solution. I tried putting my jar under /lib but connect still doesn't recognize the class. What is the connector you are adding a class to?

Comment: Adding the jar under /lib worked for me under 2 connectors: MongoDB and S3. It should work. I believe you should double check your setup.